# Get same unique id for same string

Tags: java

Is there a way to find the same integer/long or any digit number equivalent to a given string using java.

e.g If i give a string "Java_programming" it should give me always something like "7287272" digit.

The generated digit/number should be unique i.e. it should always generate "123" for "xyz" not "123" for "abc".

Comment: Use the `hashCode()` method inherited from the `Object` class but overridden in `String`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis hashcode method can produce the same integer for 2 different strings

Comment: @gma Why is that a problem? OP means same ID for the same string or hasn't made it clear otherwise.

Comment: I think Two different string can have same Hash code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I agree, it was just to give to @Manish all the implications using `hashCode`.

Answer (score 6):

Call the [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) method of your `String` object.

I.e :

```
String t = "Java_programming";
String t2 = "Java_programming";
System.out.println(t.hashCode());
System.out.println(t2.hashCode());
```

Gives :

> 748582308
> 748582308

Using `hashCode` in this case will meet your requirements (as you formuled it) but be careful, two different `String` can produce the **SAME** `hashCode` value ! (see @Dirk example)

Comment: Hash code might meet the requirements, but I'd be careful: it's pretty easy to produce string values, where the hash codes collide. E.g., `"\u001f"` and `"\u0001\u0000"` will produce the same hash code under the algorithm described for String.hashCode (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode())

Answer (score 3):

What are your requirements? You could just use a `new BigInteger("somestring".toBytes("UTF-8")).toString()` to convert the string to a number, but will it do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a SHA-1 out of the string and use that as a key?

```
static HashFunction hashFunction = Hashing.sha1();
public static byte[] getHash(final String string) {
  HashCode hashCode = hashFunction.newHasher().putBytes(string.getBytes).hash();
  return hashCode.asBytes();
}
```

You can then do `Bytes.toInt(hash)` or `Bytes.toLong(hash)`

Comment: will it always give the unique int/long for different string. i.e. always "123" for "xyz" and always "789" for "abc" but not "123" for "awe" something like.

Comment: Well, since its a hashing algorithm (SHA-1) it is not 100% guaranteed to give unique hashes. SHA-1 produces a 160bit hash and there is a chance of collusion among 2^51 hashes (still only a chance). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1 :) I used SHA-1 for hashing millions of data segments and have not found a collusion yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use String.hashCode() method on string.
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) you find more details how integer returned by this method is created

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want that 2 different String have to give always 2 different identifiers.
`String.hashCode()` can do what you want, the same string will give always the same ID but 2 different strings can also give the same ID.

If you want a **unique** identifier you can i.e. concatenate each byte character value from your string.

Answer (score 0):

First take your string and convert it to a sequence of bytes:

```
String a = "hello";

byte[] b = a.getBytes();
```

Now convert the bytes to a numeric representation, using `BigInteger`

```
BigInteger c = new BigInteger(b);
```

Finally, convert the `BigInteger` back to a string using its `toString()` method

```
String d = c.toString();
```

You are guaranteed to get the same output for the same input, and different outputs for different inputs. You can combine all of these into one step by doing

```
String d = new BigInteger(a.getBytes()).toString();
```